# Not quite sure about this derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I am not quite sure why the coefficient for sinθ x dr/dt x dθ/dt is 2. I thought it was 1.

Could somebody please explain to me where the 2 comes from

Comment: Which is independent and depend variable

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

The 2 comes from one term $-\dot r \dot \theta \sin\theta$ that comes from derivating $\dot r \cos \theta$ and an identical term that comes from derivating $- r \dot\theta \sin\theta$.